# Problem understanding probabilistic generative models for classification

Tags: machine-learning, classification, probability, bayesian

I am a student and I am studying machine learning. I am focusing on **probabilistic generative models for classification** and I am having some troubles understanding this topic.

In the slide of my professor it is written the following:

[image]

which I don't understand.

So far, I have understood that in the generative probailistic models, we ant to estimate $P(C_i|x)$, which is the probability of having class $i$ given a data $x$, using the likelihood and the Bayes theorem.

So, it starts by writing the Bayes rule, but the the slides says that we can write this as a sigmoid, **but why?**

If I have to try to give an answer to it, I would say because the sigmoid gives a number from $0$ to $1$, and so a probability, but it is just a guess I am doing.

Moreover, it continues by saying that we can use a gaussian distribution for $P(x|C_i)$, and so $P(x|C_i)=N(\mu ,\sigma )$, and so :

[image]

I don't understand what it is doing, can somebody please help me?

I don't know if my question is clear so sorry if it is not but I am really confused. If it is not lcear please tell me I will try to edit it. Thanks in advance.

**Note:** if it can be useful, this has been taken from the Bishop book at **page 197**

Comment: What book is the Bishop book?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding is:

1. The first line is OK - it derives from Bayes Rule
2. **Assume** that this probability follows a logistic function, that is that

$$P(C_1|x) = \frac{1}{1+exp(-a)}$$

3. Then if

$$ y = \frac{1}{1+exp(-z)}$$

then

$$ z = ln(\frac{y}{1-y})$$

(some lines below but with $a$ and $\sigma$)

4. Therefore:

$$ a = ln(\frac{P(C_1|x)}{1-P(C_1|x)})$$

5. If there are only two classes then $1-P(C_1|x)= P(C_2|x)$.
6. Then

$$a = ln(\frac{P(C_1|x)}{P(C_2|x)}$$

7. Using Bayes on $P(C_1|x)$ and $P(C_2|x)$

$$a = ln(\frac{P(x|C_1) P(C_1)}{P(x|C_2)P(C_2)}$$

8. The whole thing now is to model $P(x|C_i)$. He **assumes** that it is a normal distribution. And from there you should the second set of equations. The important part (as far as I remember) is that the two covariance matrix (for $C_1$ and for $C_2$) are the same. I do not have access to the book now but I will look it up tomorrow and see if there is any difficult step in the derivations.

**tldr:** The whole point is he assumes that the probability as a logistic, then he gets the formula for the $a$, then he assumes a normal distribution for $P(x|C_i)$, then he assumes same covariance matrix.